# Line breaks are missing in \author if it processes the output of another command

Tags: line-breaking, author

In [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/89187/64217), I found a nice trick for dealing with lists. The code below allows to print lists with an optional separator argument.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\newcommand{\printlist}[2][,]{%
  \def\itemdelim{\def\itemdelim{#1}}% Item delimiter delayed by one cycle
  \renewcommand*{\do}[1]{\itemdelim##1}% How each item is processed
  \docsvlist{#2}}% Process CSV list
\begin{document}
$\printlist{1,2,3,4,5,6,7}$ \par
$\printlist[;]{a,b,c,d,e,f}$
\end{document}
```

However, if I use `\printlist` within the `\author` command, in combination with a newline `\\`, this won't work properly: The line break is set only for the first element of the list. For all other elements, the line break is ignored:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\newcommand{\printlist}[2][;]{%
  \def\itemdelim{\def\itemdelim{#1}}% Item delimiter delayed by one cycle
  \renewcommand*{\do}[1]{\itemdelim##1}% How each item is processed
  \docsvlist{#2}}% Process CSV list

\title{Test}
\author{\printlist[,\\]{abc,def,ghi,jkl}}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image: Failing case]

If I use a separator without line-break, e.g. `::`, the above works as expected.

[image: Successful test 1]

Adding additional line-breaks `\\` in the `\author` command also leads to the expected result:

```latex
\author{\printlisti[::]{abc,def,ghi}\\123\\456\\789}
```

[image: Successful test 2]

It seems that the combination of `\printlist` with line breaks `\\` is causing a problem. How come?

Comment: The argment to `\author` will be put inside a `tabular` where each cell forms its own group. The definitions of `\itemdelim` and `\do` are local and won't survive this first row.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Thanks. I can't draw a link between `tabular` and local `\do` or `\itemdelim`. Why are they lost after the first row?

Comment: Try `\begin{tabular}{c}\def\itemdelim{test} \\ \itemdelim \end{tabular}`. It will lead to an Undefined control sequence `\itemdelim`. You basically need `\gdef`s for every instance of `\def` and `\renewcommand`. Or prepare the list beforehand.

Comment: Ah. Now it makes sense. Thanks. One more question: While `\gdef` helps in your example, why doesn't work for my problem? Using `\gdef` in the definition of `\printlist` leads to the same result.

Comment: My previous comment wasn't precise. The first `\def\itemdelim` will be used in the first row. It's that internal `\def\itemdelim{#1}` that needs to be global (as well as the `\do` too). I hope my answer is somewhat clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument to `\author` will be typeset in a `tabular`. Each cell forms its own group thus, the internal definition of `\itemdelim` and the definition of `\do` won't survive your first row.

Essentially, this is what's happening:

```
\begin{tabular}{c}
  \def\itemdelim{test} \\
  \itemdelim
\end{tabular}
```

and the same for `\do`, though in the second row that will have the same definition as outside of `tabular` and won't lead to an error message.

---

You will need to do the definitions of `\itemdelim` (for the non-first entry) and `\do` global:

```
\newcommand{\printlist}[2][;]{%
  \def\itemdelim{\gdef\itemdelim{#1}}%
  \gdef\do##1{\itemdelim##1}%
  \docsvlist{#2}}
\author{\printlist[,\\]{abc,def,ghi,jkl}}
```

Though, you could apply the “trick” of `\itemdelim` directly for `\do` and skip `\itemdelim` by using `#1` directly:

```
\newcommand{\printlist}[2][;]{%
  \def\do##1{##1\gdef\do####1{#1####1}}%
  \docsvlist{#2}}
\author{\printlist[,\\]{abc,def,ghi,jkl}}
```

With another auxilliary macro like `\defdo` we can avoid defining `\do` global (at the cost of another document-wide defined macro):

```
\newcommand*\defdo[1]{%
  \def\do##1{#1\defdo{#1}##1}}%
\newcommand{\printlist}[2][;]{%
  \def\do##1{##1\defdo{#1}}%
  \docsvlist{#2}}%
\author{\printlist[,\\]{abc,def,ghi,jkl}}
```

This sneaks the definition of `\do` from row to row behind the `\\` so that it will be available in the next row.

---

Alternatively, you could pre-process the list and just forward that to `\author`:

```
\newcommand{\savelist}[3][;]{%
  \renewcommand*\do[1]{%
    \newcommand*#3{##1}%
    \renewcommand*\do[1]{%
      \appto#3{#1####1}%
    }%
  }%
  \docsvlist{#2}}
\savelist[,\\]{abc,def,ghi,jkl}\authors
\author{\authors}
```

In this case, the definition of `\do` is also “global” because it is defined on the top level of the document.

Defining `\do` global shouldn't create a conflict since every other code that uses `\do` should have defined it itself without assuming any definition. Mixing global and local assignments/definitions [could be messy](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/561115/16595), though, so using `\savelist` might be preferable.

---

Looking beyond `etoolbox`, LaTeX3's `l3clist` package provides `\clist_use:Nn` which doesn't need any definitions to just place something (`#1` = `,\\`) between a list's entries:

```
\documentclass{article}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\printlist}{ O{;} m}{
  \clist_set:Nn \l_tmpa_clist {#2}
  \clist_use:Nn \l_tmpa_clist {#1}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\author{\printlist[,\\]{abc,def,ghi,jkl}}
\title{Test}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot! Are there any potential side effects when defining `\do` globally? Therefore pre-processing the list might be a bit safer, right?

Comment: @normanius No, there shouldn't be a conflict with other usages of `\do`. But `\savelist` still seems like a cleaner approach. I've updated my answer with a LaTeX3 solution that works without having to use any definitions. (I left out a [low-level implementation](https://github.com/Qrrbrbirlbel/tex.sx/blob/master/679067.tex) of a simple `,`-list parser because I don't think you want to use that over `\savelist` or the LaTeX3 solution.)

Comment: Thank you so much. I wish I could upvote your answer more than once.